# Linker Error in Objective-C static library with unit testing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, linker-errors, static-libraries

In my Cocoa Touch static library project, I have a target set apart for unit testing with OCUnit. When I build the project, I have several unit tests that are supposed to automatically run, but when I actually build the project, I get this linker errors:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ObjectIntTreeMap_ObjectEntry", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-ObjectIntTreeMap_ObjectEntry in libMyLib.a(ObjectIntTreeMap.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I know, I am linking the libraries properly (in targets / Tests / Link Binary With Libraries, I have the main project listed there).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

My problem was that I had not the class `ObjectIntTreeMap_ObjectEntry`, and a global variable, and that was what caused my error.

Hope this helps others with the same problem

P.S. I am using [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) now